# How to Speed Up Protobuf Compilation on Travis

Tags: performance, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm attempting to improve the Travis build time on my repository

At present, Travis builds take 40 minutes. We've already cached apt and pip but it seems that the main overhead from installing the packages.

Here's what the cache section of my .yml file looks like

```
cache:
    - apt
    - pip
    - directories:
        - /opt/python
        - /opt/ros/kinetic/
        - ${WORKSPACE}/src/protobuf
```

A breakdown of the Travis log shows that compiling Protobuf takes around 30 minutes. We have considered dumping the repository into a docker container and running a pre-built image to remove the overhead of compiling the packages. However, my tech lead objects to this as he wishes to stay up to date with the latest packages.

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to speed up the build.

Thank you